# How to print a float that its fractional part is zero

Tags: c++, floating-point

In the C++ language I want to print a float number like `2.0` with it's fractional part and without using `fixed` and `setpresicion`. How can I do that?
I had to print several double numbers each has a different length of fractional part (and some has a `.0`  only). When displaying, I want that every number has exactly its miningful numbers after decimal point with no extra zeroes despite those with one zero. As you know `cout` dose not print fractional part of a float if it is a zero only. So I want to fix this problems and it seems that using `fixed` and `setprecision` dosn't work properly.

Comment: May I ask *why* you don't want to use `fixed` and `setprecision`? Is this a puzzle or something like that? You *could* use `printf` format specifiers.

Comment: `std::cout << "2.0";` ? Please provide more context...

Comment: Because cout is bloated.

Comment: To me, this seems a bit like asking how to remove a screw without using a screwdriver. The question would be improved by explaining your criteria for a good method. Otherwise, you may get suggestions that are just as "bad" as the ways you do not want to use.

Comment: Your words "I want that every number has exactly its miningful numbers after decimal point **with no extra zeroes**" and your next sentence "Also as you know `cout` dose not print fractional part of a float if it is a zero only" are in direct conflict with other.

Comment: I had to print several double numbers each has a different length of fractional part (and some has a ```.0``` only). When displaying, I want that every number has exactly its miningful numbers after decimal point with no extra zeroes despite those with one zero. As you know ```cout``` dose not print fractional part of a float if it is a zero only. So I want to fix this problems and it seems that using ```fixed``` and ```setprecision``` dosn't work properly.

Comment: How doesn't it work properly? Show your code, and the output you get.

Comment: I tried something like following code and it works (displays every number with exactly its meaningful numbers after decimal point with no extra zeroes, despite those with one zero.): ```double x; cin >> x; cout << x; int xint = x; if(x == xint){cout << ".0"};```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really do not want to use `setprecision` and `fixed`. You can use a `template`.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

// d = The decimal places you want.
template<int d> 
std::ostream& fixed(std::ostream& os){
    os.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield); 
    os.precision(d); 
    return os; 
}

int main(){
    double d = 2.0;
    std::cout << fixed<2> << d;
}
```